# how to extract OSM data to as many layers as possible in DXF( or multiple DXF file) as path for illustrator use?

Tags: qgis, layers, export, dxf

So i am just touching QGIS, mainly to explorer way to use map data for my animation. Here's my first try to make it clear to understand what I am aiming for:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jhC-C5f-K68

Right now I can only output 2 layers , "lines any" that include all road, and "multilinestrings any" that include only the main road (seems to be).

I understand the map got a lot of tags and I wish to export them individually, say the highway, small road, bike lane, waterway, building, nature, etc.

googling quite a lot but to no avail.

Answer (score 1):

In QGIS, you might install the `QuickMapServices` and `QuickOSM` plugin.

From the first, you get an Openstreetmap background, and you can zoom to your area of interest.

Then start the QuickOSM plugin, and enter `highway` for key and `primary` for value. Hit `Run query`, and you get only the primary roads, and some points on them (traffic lights etc). You might delete the points layer if you don't need them.

Do the same with motorways, secondary and tertiary highways and so on. Every query generates a new layer to style and export as you wish.

See the [OSM wiki](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Key:highway) or the dropdown list of the plugin for valid highway values.

Answer (score 0):

https://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/downloading_osm_data.html

Searching and Downloading OpenStreetMap Data using plugins.